# Is there a limit to the number of Dragon Souls you can carry?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a limit on how many Dragon Souls you can store? A couple of times after a battle, the dragon does not give me a soul and doesn't even disintegrate. Most times this happens I'll have at least 1-4 souls in my inventory.

Comment: not giving soul is a bug, though a minor one, and no limit I know of, if there is it's probably around 2 billion (American).

Comment: I think this can happen if you search his body before the soul is added.

Answer (score 10):

If a respawned Dragon is killed again (as in, those that rest atop Word Walls outside of dungeons), it will not yield any Dragon Souls.

(source: [elderscrolls wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Soul))

It's possible you killed one of these respawning Dragon. Do you remember if this happened at a World Wall?

There's also a link of known bugs on that page.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine so, I have at least 30 souls on my inventory, so I havent seen any indication of a limit

Answer (score 1):

> A couple of times after a battle, the dragon does not give me a soul and doesn't even disintegrate.

This issue should have been fixed as of [Patch 1.2](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch#Version_1.2):

> Fixed rare issue with dragons not properly giving souls after death

Souls of killed dragons should always be absorbed by the player character (spoiler: except when you [currently have a particular set of Dragonborn DLC quests active](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Miraak_%28NPC%29)). There a bug, though, regarding respawned dragons not giving up souls after death. This has been fixed by the **[Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/19/?)**:

> Fixed some encounter dragons not burning up nor giving the player a soul when slain (respawned dragons were not being properly reset)

<sup>([Parts of this answer are from an answer of mine in another question here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/118035/4797))</sup>

Answer (score -2):

There's not. I have about 25, but like that other guy said, respawned dragons will not give you their souls.

Answer (score -2):

In this period of 2017 Skyrim should have no limit of the dragon souls, I personally have 42 dragon souls. So in case you were In 2013 or 2014 I may be off on the knowledge.