# Skyrim ps3- Dragon Glitching

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

There is a dragon, south of Markarth, that is registered as an enemy on the mini map, but when I go to kill it, it doesn't start attacking me like it should. I get it's health points to 0, but it doesn't move at all, and I can't absorb it's soul. I tried reloading the game, turning my ps3 off and on again, and it's still glitching... HELP :(

Comment: Can't you just ignore it?

Comment: Have you tried healing it and killing it again?

Comment: I had the same problem with three dragons and I ignored them all, you will be left with as many as 20-25 drag souls left even after you learn all shouts, so no worries ;]   also, you might wanna see this http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35754/why-didnt-i-get-to-absorb-a-dragon-soul-after-its-death